# imshow window is cutoff

Tags: opencv, imshow

So my problem is this: I usually connect my laptop to an external screen, and everything works fine, until I need to bring my laptop to the university for a progress report. When my laptop is not connected to an external screen, the window showed by imshow is cut off at the bottom, as shown in this picture.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so, can you share how to fix this? My laptop uses windows 10, python 3.6.4 and opencv 3.3.0.

My current code is a bit long so I will just give the flow here:
Read an image with imread, crop the ROI from it, convert the ROI to gray scale with cvtColor, add a mask to filter out colors with cv2.inRange, apply that mask on the gray scale image with bitwise_and, then do a perspective change with getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective, save the images with imwrite, finally showing the results with imshow and waitkey.

Below are sample lines of code for each step.

[image: Bottom part is cut off]

'image' and 'gray' are 480x360 images, 'cropped' and 'white_lanes' are 480x150 images, and mapped is a 480x550 image

My code:

```
image = cv2.imread(args["data"])

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cropped = gray[210:360]

mask_white = cv2.inRange(cropped, 220, 255)

white_lanes = cv2.bitwise_and(cropped, mask_white)

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)

mapped = cv2.warpPerspective(white_lanes, M, (wlwidth+2*expansionx, wlheight+expansiony))

filename=args["data"][11:-4]

cv2.imwrite("cropmap{}.jpg".format(filename), cropmap)

cv2.imshow("Cropped Gray Image", cropped)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: As your code is not provided... a simple hint towards your answer: use a form of image autoresizer. Your image size seems to be coded static and not dynamic. Keep proportions in mind. And use "!" infornt of your imagelink... it will then show it to us ;p

Comment: Hi @ZF007, I edited the post as you suggested. Yes, my image sizes used static codes and the proportions of the images showed by imshow are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you show `cv2.imshow("Cropped Gray Image", cropped)` but not `cv2.imshow("Mapped Image", mapped)` which clearly is show in your posted image.

You perform with `mapped = cv2.warpPerspective(white_lanes, M, (wlwidth+2*expansionx, wlheight+expansiony))` a task but doesn't show dimensions in your code. Thus hard to tell if it fits within your laptop screensize.

Thus add...

`resized_mapped_image = cv2.resize(mapped, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))`

.. then `cv2.imshow("Mapped Image", resized_mapped_image)`

..which should downsize image by half and solve the issue.

Otherwise...:

1. how does your image array size looks just before `M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)` ?
2. Check that for each subsequent step...
3. Also, after cropped you show image... but the image shown shows values on the x-axis... which doesn't make sense with `cv2.imshow("Cropped Gray Image", cropped)`
   as `cv2.imshow("Mapped Image", mapped)` should be replaced with `cv2.imshow("Cropped Gray Image", cropped)`.. but then its only the cropped version shown....

Comment: 3. Ah, actually, I showed multiple pictures by stacking them like this:
https://pastebin.com/nvR0Bz2t

Comment: for that... use a locationlist + name [img1, img2, img3) and loop through it with a for-loop.

Comment: Well, your suggestion did not work but still thank you for your advice :D

I gave up on this problem and decided to continue with other parts of the project. Now, after a while, I came back and poof, problem is gone. Magic. I didn't even change the code. Not sure what happened either :\

Comment: These things happen... perhaps some code remnants from earlier trial and error were purged from the system. My experience with windows is to do every-now and then a cold boot run while all power (incl. screens) is off to purge all code from ddr-mem and graphics cards. Some vendors place LEDs to do that kind of job but some parts are left untouched by it while a starting CPU/fan drains all power left in the system. Anyway GL.